# convergence of $\sum_1^ \infty n^2 e^{- \sqrt{n} }$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm trying to determine if $\sum_1^ \infty  n^2 e^{- \sqrt{n} }$ converges.
For divergence test, I got 0 (well my calculator did... I'm not entirely sure how to limit this...) . For ratio test, I got 1. For root test, I got 0. Now I'm trying to use comparison test but i'm not sure what to compare it with....

Comment: The root test should give you $1$, as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since $e^x > x^k$ $\forall k \in \mathbb{N}$ (when $x$ is big enough), there exists $N>0$ such that $e^{\sqrt{n}}>\sqrt{n}^8$ $\forall n>N$
So
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{e^{\sqrt{n}}} = \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{n^2}{e^{\sqrt{n}}} + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{e^{\sqrt{n}}} \leq const. + \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{{\sqrt{n}^{8}}} = const. + \sum_{n=N+1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2} < + \infty
\end{equation}

Comment: Along the same lines, by the power series for $e^x$, we have $e^{\sqrt{n}}\gt \frac{(\sqrt{n})^8}{8!}$.

Answer (score 6):

The integral test works.

$$\int_1^\infty x^2 e^{-\sqrt x} \, \mathrm d x = 2 \int_1^\infty x^5 e^{-x} \, \mathrm d x = \frac {652} e$$